# How to repeat an element in a list by the number of times that is the magnitude of that element

Tags: python

The question I am trying to answer is this:
Create a function `numstack(n)` that returns a list of integers from 1 to n (inclusively) but where each integer  mm  in the list appears, consecutively, a total of  mm  times, so that, for example:
`numstack(4) = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]`

So far my best attempt has been:

```
def numstack(n):
for i in range(1,n+1):
    z = [i]*i
            
return z
```

`print(numstack(3))`

But this is far from correct, any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to get what you want. You already seem to know what `[i]*i` does.

```
def numstack(n):
    return [j for i in range(1, n + 1) for j in [i]*i]


print(numstack(4))
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

From the comments a better approach would be to write the comprehension as `return [i for i in range(1, n + 1) for j in range(i)]`

Comment: `[i for i in range(1, n + 1) for _ in range(i)]`

Comment: Complicated will be smth like this: `sum(([i] * i for i in range(1, n + 1)), [])`

Comment: @OlvinRoght or `[*chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, *[range(1, n + 1)]*2))]` :p

Comment: Your look more obvious :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one more loop like this:

```py
def numstack(n):
    result = []  # we put results here
    for i in range(1, n + 1):  # for each number <1,n>
        for _ in range(1, i + 1):  # repeat i times
            result.append(i)  # insert "i" to the result list
    return result

print(numstack(5))
```

Using `[i]*i` construction:

```py
def numstack(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        res += [i] * i
    return res

print(numstack(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is not so bad, we can extend it to arrive at the solution.

```
def numstack(n): 
     result = [] 
     for i in range(1,n+1): 
         z = [i]*i 
         result.extend(z) 
          
     return result
```

Shorter solution with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain                                                                                                                                                                                                        
def numstack(n): 
     return list(chain.from_iterable([i]*i for i in range(1, n + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you:

```
def numstack(n):
    num = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        data = []
        data.append(i)
        num.append(data * i)
    result = [item for sublist in num for item in sublist]
    return result
```